# Pending Changes Visual Studio 2013, Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

When using Visual Studio 2013 and trying to get the View Pending Changes window I get the following message:

Team Foundation Server is not the current Source Control plug-in. Change Plug-in

I'm using Git

If I change Git to Team Foundation Server, what will happen to my code that on

https://my-account.visualstudio.com/

Can I just go ahead and change to Team Foundation Server, without and repercussions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you change to TFVC you will no longer be able to access your source in Git. You need to click the 'home' button and then select "Changes". This is different from the "Pending Changes" window and is Git specific.